# Create a contact from web

Tags: whatsapp

How can I create contact in web.whatsapp.com? I would like how to do it exactly from web, not mobile. It seems this option is not included.

I have tried to enter phone or name directly and "enter" it but it only lists existing users or nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

At this time is not possible.

## Explanation

I searched for this some time ago and just did it again.

- The Web UI doesn't include any hint about how to do this.
- The [Official Web FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/web?lg=en) doesn't include a topic about this.

Comment: I feared that. Thx Ruben!